# Variadic Parameters in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a very simple piece of code which is using Variadic Parameters in Swift Language.

[image]

I don't understand why it is complaining. Is'nt Double... equavalent to [Double]

I know I can pass like this: printList(2,3,4,5).

I guess Variadic is different from what I thought. You can pass multiple arguments. It is about arguments not passing in collections.

Comment: An array is just a single argument. It's not variadic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want to pass an array in a function,do it like this**

```
func printList(numbers:[Double]){

}

let numbers = [Double](count: 5, repeatedValue: 0.0)

printList(numbers)
```

**If you want to pass in same kind of input,but number is not known,you do it like this**

```
func printList(numbers:Double...){

}

printList(0.0,0.0,0.0)
printList(0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration of

```
func printList (numbers:Double...) {}
```

expects each argument passed to `printList` to be a `Double`.  It is thus invoked like this:

```
printList (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```

If instead you invoke it like this:

```
printList ([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0])
```

then you are invoking your `printList` on `[Double]`, not the required `Double`, and thus the compiler will flag that call site.

One of the operators missing from Swift is `apply` (so called in Scheme and other languages) which takes a function and a Sequence and destructures the seqeunce as individual arguments to the function.  Thus:

```
apply (printList, arguments: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
```

would 'translate' to:

```
printList (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```

**Importantly**, you can of course define two functions as:

```
func pL (numbers:Double...) { println (numbers) }  // better, use pL(numbers)!
func pL (numbers:[Double])  { println (numbers) }
```

and then get your desired behavior:

```
  7> pL (1.0, 2.0)
[1.0, 2.0]
  8> pL ([1.0, 2.0])
[1.0, 2.0]
```